# PHP While loop Notice: Undefined offset

Tags: php, while-loop

I am fixing an existing PHP code

I get error

`Notice: Undefined offset: 6`

The PHP code will look like below. It is a big while loop. Here I just show the main section.

```
$data = Array
(
    [0] => 1
)

$data2 = Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 12
    [3] => 15
    [4] => 17
    [5] => 23
)


$i = 0;
while($data[$i]){
    array_push($data,$data2);
    $i++;
}
```

Also,

Sometimes, I get error

`Notice: Undefined offset: 4`

for

```
$data2 = Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 34
    [2] => 56
    [3] => 78
    [4] => 83
)
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Try a `foreach` loop instead : http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: `while( isset($data[$i]) ) {` The condition needs to be boolean `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Though you'd be best to use a `foreach` loop to traverse through an array.

Comment: What???? I don't understand what you are doing here... you are adding the whole array `$data2` to the end of `$data` while there is a value in `$data` that sounds non-sense to me...?

Comment: @JuniusRendel I know this code is confusing. I am still trying to figure out what was in developer's mind when he wrote this code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use foreach for iterating through arrays:

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {}
```

Your warning with `while` is that you do check if this array position exists right. Use this instead:

```
while(isset($data[$i])){}
```

Comment: **Note:** Using `isset` in the `while` condition because the condition needs to equate to boolean `TRUE`/`FALSE`; which `isset` will do (also handling the undefined offset).

Comment: Thanks Richard Reiber and @ʰᵈˑ